# replace in java using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

suppose I have a string

```
  String = ".... helllo.... good \"morning\" .....\" "
```

I want to get output as

```
  helllo good morning
```

How can I do that using regular expression in Java?

Comment: several ways... for example?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the `.` and the `"` ? This question is really unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to remove the `.` and the `"`, then you can do

```
 str = str.replaceAll("\"|\\.", "");
```

This regular expression replaces any `"` (escaped as `\"` because in a java string literal) or (`|`) `.` (escaped first as `\.` because in a regex then as `\\.` because a `\` must be escaped in a java string literal) by nothing (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you just want to ***maintain*** the space character and letters, you can use the following regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z\s]+
```

If you also want to include numbers:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
```

Just replace the matches of that regular expression by an empty string.

**Edit:**

If you just want to do the opposite (***remove*** certain characters, like `.` and `"`), then you can check `@dystroy` answer.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
String yourString = ".... helllo.... good \"morning\" .....\" ";
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll("[.\\\"]", ""));
```

outputs `helllo good morning`

Comment: Why exactly do you use `(.*?)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = ".... helllo.... good \"morning\" .....\" ";
    str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").replaceAll("  +", " ");

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

Here is a way to do it using simple replace methods of String class.

```
    String s = ".... helllo.... good \"morning\" .....\" ";
    s = s.replace(".","").replace("\"", "");
    System.out.println(s);
```